# Eclipse auto suggest list very slow

Tags: eclipse, autosuggest

By auto suggest, I mean that intellisense that pops up when I write something. My problem is that if I write something like `btnMyButton.`  after typing `.` I get to wait a few seconds until eclipse populates the list with events for button. I am using Eclipse to develop Android applications.

Can this be sped up?  I have a Quad Core processor and 4 GB of ram. The rest of Eclipse is working fine.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this same problem - Eclipse with Android, the code-completion popups take forever.  Dunno why yet.

Comment: Interestingly, I have this issue with a C++ project, but not my Java projects.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was also experiencing this problem.  I found my answer here:

https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/85dc1aae3bafff5e

In summary:

> turn off JAX-WS Proposals in Content Assist

*Window > Preferences --> Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced*

Comment: I don't have JAX-WS in there... thank you for anwser anyway, it might help others.

Comment: I don't have "JAX-WS Proposals" in that list. I have unchecked everything other than "Java Proposals" and Eclipse is still very slow.

Comment: You can also try changing the Auto Activation parameters. You can either disable it completely or you can increase the "delay" to make sure it does not hang your Editor while you are typing.

Comment: Same Problem, but no "JAX-WS" present, disabling "SWT Template Proposal" and "Chain Template Proposal" resulted in a huge speedup. (On top some of the exceptions thrown sometimes did disappear from the log...)

Comment: The problem went away for me after disabling Java Proposals (Code Recommenders) and enabling Java Proposals instead (without the Code Recommenders tag)

Answer (score 3):

When I changed ***delay*** to 1 (ms) it solved autocompletion problem in Eclipse for C++.it is now very fast:
[image: Hi.when i changed delay to 1(ms) it solved autocompletion problem in eclipse for c++.it is now very fast]

Comment: Great!! What a simple and powerful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked "Fill method arguments and show guessed arguments" under Window > Preferences --> Java > Editor > Content Assist

This improved the content assist speed in my Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

**Uncheck all, other than** `API Tools Proposals` and `Java Proposals` in `Window > Preferences --> Java > Editor > Content Assist`.

Refer to the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

you can add disable auto activation in 
Window > Preferences --> Java > Editor > Content Assist

This way you can activate it when you need it by Ctrl + Space

Answer (score -4):

Try clicking CTRL + Space when you want to see the menu is it still slow?

Comment: It is slow in the case of controls, like buttons, imageviews etc. If I have a class and i type Classname.getSOmeMember() the menu is very fast.

Comment: I see Eclipse being slower in Windows 7 and faster on Windows XP