# Debugging Android 'hello world' app with Eclipse, variable view super slow

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, variables, view

I have installed latest version Eclipse Classic (3.7.1),
Android sdk (r16)
jdk x64 6u30 (also tried 6u25 and ver. 7)
Platform tools etc.

My computer specs: Intel i5-2500K, 16GB DDR3 Ram.
OS: Win 7 (x64 Prof), also tried in VirtualBox (WinXP SP3 x32).

So i followed the official 'Hello World' tutorial from Google site:

```
package com.test.AndroidApp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TestAppActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello, Android...."); // BREAKPOINT HERE
    setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

console messages when starting debugger:

```
[2012-02-11 00:45:39 - hello] ------------------------------
[2012-02-11 00:45:39 - hello] Android Launch!
[2012-02-11 00:45:39 - hello] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-11 00:45:39 - hello] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloActivity activity launch
[2012-02-11 00:45:39 - hello] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'avd' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-02-11 00:45:39 - hello] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avd'
[2012-02-11 00:45:42 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
[2012-02-11 00:45:42 - hello] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-02-11 00:45:42 - hello] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-02-11 00:45:51 - hello] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-11 00:45:51 - hello] Uploading hello.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-11 00:45:51 - hello] Installing hello.apk...
[2012-02-11 00:45:55 - hello] Success!
[2012-02-11 00:45:55 - hello] Starting activity com.example.helloandroid.HelloActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-02-11 00:45:55 - hello] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.helloandroid/.HelloActivity }
[2012-02-11 00:45:56 - hello] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.example.helloandroid' on port 8627
```

And when the debugger hits the breakpoint, i point mouse cursor to the 'tv' variable, the Variable hint window is displayed and is being filled veeeeeery slowly.
It takes 0.5-1 sec to display each member of tv (TextView), by display i mean to draw variable icon, name and value.

While the debugger displays all members of 'tv' i can scroll it down to the bottom, select any variable (i don't see them, but i can select them if i click somewhere to the left of the hint window)  and most interesting part - i can see var member value! (without name, only value).

It takes about 1 minute to display all members of 'tv'. (processor load is 0-2% during this time)
If i close hint window, and open it again - the process repeats, taking 1 minute again.

Variables view window behaves the same way as a hint popup window. (i open up 'tv' variable and it takes 1 min. to display all its members).

I tried doing the same in VirtualBox machine with winxp32, no luck.
I tried using another computer at the office (core E6600, win 7 prof x64) - no luck.

I tried installing Eclipse on MacOs (hackintosh using the same machine) - works blazingly fast.

After Googling about this problem i found the same bug report, dated 2006, and it has been fixed in eclipse 3.1.6.

Is it only me?
I didn't find anyone else mentioning this problem. Maybe no one else has installed latest eclipse and adt plugin yet?

p.s.
I've developed apps for iOs on the same machine, and there was no such problem.

I also have tried to debug simple Java project - variable hint and window works fast!

Comment: This is really something that you should be asking over on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same issue as this question

[Eclipse auto suggest list very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980022/eclipse-auto-suggest-list-very-slow/4065094#4065094)

I had the same problem and found my answer here

https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/85dc1aae3bafff5e

In summary - "turn off JAX-WS Proposals in Content Assist

Window > Preferences --> Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced "

Comment: No, if i type tv.  auto suggest list popups very quickly, and is already populated.

Comment: I don't have JAX-WS proposals in ContentAssist-Advanced.

Answer (score -1):

Wow... Look how far we've come.

You can download Android Studio now.