# (Bad) lagg on auto complete in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Basically when I auto complete on Eclipse (By pressing CTRL+Space) the program laggs for about 5 seconds. This is getting really annoying because I use the auto complete alot. How do I fix this?

The workspace I'm working on is located on a NAS with a 1Gbit/s connection. Could this be causing it?

Thanks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your connection. Whats your system configuration, becasue eclipse itself is a Java program and it needs decent memory to run.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980022/eclipse-auto-suggest-list-very-slow) - turns out that disabling JAX-WS proposals worked for someone. Failing that, a reinstall might do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if problem exists with local resources too

   Create a local workspace and open it with same eclipse instance. Now create a simple java project by new project wizard at your local machine inside this workapce and try code completion there. If it's still slow go to Step 2.
   *(by the way - I wouldn't store workspace information on remote side, but always local)*
2. Check proposal kinds

   If it's not a network issue and the problem still exists on a simple local workplace with local sources you should inspect your proposal setup as shown in next picture.Maybe one of the proposal kinds is slowing down your IDE. You can experiment with turning off proposal kinds sequential to find the problematic one.

   [image: Advanced settings code completion]
3. System requirements

   If you got stil the problem after doing Step 1-2 maybe your system has not enough power/memory to provide eclipse (*but normally not the reason -  I am using eclipse at Linux on an old T61 notebook with 4 GB Ram + SSD and it works fine!*)