# Why system.out.println() make my Eclipse not responding

Tags: java, eclipse

Every time i write `system.out.println()` code, Eclipse will start to not responding. It starts to not responding after i put a dot `.` next to `system`. I try to use sysout shortcut but it still the same. I try to write and copy `system.out.println()` on notepad and paste it on Eclipse and it works.

Comment: It may be trying to load the code reccomender

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980022/eclipse-auto-suggest-list-very-slow)?

Comment: already disable Code Recommender, Java Proposals, SWT Template and Chain Template but still the same. Thank you for the answers anyway <3

Comment: There are too many causes which makes your Eclipse slow such as import a amount of projects, lack sufficient memory, enable auto build configuration, and so on.

Comment: Current versions of Eclipse do not contain Code Recommenders. You are probably using an outdated Eclipse version. But the reason for the unresponsiveness is probably not the outdated Eclipse version but most likely a plug-in you have installed (as a slow Java content assist does not block the UI). To find out by which plug-in it is caused, enable _Window > Preferences: General > UI Responsiveness Monitoring_.

Comment: I already use Eclipse 2019-09 and i did not installed any plugin