# Eclipse goes unresponsive when a period character is typed

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, ide

I have been using eclipse for many months without any issues now. Today I fired it up and continued working on my project. Whenever I type the "." in SomeClass." it immediately goes unresponsive and the only way to close it is to kill it using the taks manager. I tried reinstalling the program but that didnt help. Im using eclipse 2020-06 with java. Can someone please help me? Also I don't know how to debug eclipse and find the crash logs and stuff like that so if you need anything please tell me where I can find it. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Im not sure what changed but it doesnt crash immediately anymore. If I hit ctrl+space though it says computing proposals for a while and then gives me this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE9mK.png

Comment: A period just on its own, or directly following a symbol like `SomeClass.`?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you use Ctrl-Space to autocomplete?

Comment: It doesnt seem to happen inside strings and numbers

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3980022/10077

Comment: I fixed the problem by restoring my autocomplete settings to default. I dont know hwat happened to them in the first place